# как закрыть форму родительскую, при открытии новой формы дочерней

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Есть толстое приложение, в котором по клику на кнопке вызывается форма , внутри которой поле ввода, и кнопки по типу: подтвердить, отменить, пропустить.

Мне нужно, что бы при клике на вызванной форме кнопки "пропустить", вызывалась другая форма и закрывалась уже вызванная ранее.

У меня получилось реализовать только вызов новой формы, но не понимаю как закрыть первую вызванную форму

Обработчик клика на главной форме кнопки: MainForm.cs

```
private void btMovingSclad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //проверка состояния сетевого подключения
        if (!NetworkConnect(btSladEnter.Text)) return;
        String ZONE_NAME = "";
        String STACK_NAME = "";
        int POCKET_NUMBER = 0;
        String Barcode = "";
        //ввод складского объекта
        DataTable tbl = Nsi.GetSkladObjects();
        WaitMessageForm.EndWait();

        Barcode = TextBoxForm.InputValue(" Сканирование штрихкода штабеля", "");
        if (Barcode != "")
        {
            var s = Barcode;
            var pattern = @"([^.]*)\.([^.]*)\.([^.]*)";
            var regex = new Regex(pattern);

            if (!regex.IsMatch(s))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка!\nСчитанный штрих-код не является штрих-кодом штабеля ТЭСЦ-3",
                                "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                var str = Barcode;
                var splitted = str.Split('.');
                ZONE_NAME = splitted[0];
                STACK_NAME = splitted[1];
                POCKET_NUMBER = Convert.ToInt32(splitted[2]);
            }

            //создание и инициализация формы пакета труб
            ScanNumbersForm dlg = new ScanNumbersForm();
            dlg.Packet.Attributes["ZONE_NAME"] = ZONE_NAME;
            dlg.Packet.Attributes["STACK_NAME"] = STACK_NAME;
            dlg.Packet.Attributes["POCKET_NUMBER"] = POCKET_NUMBER;
            dlg.OnInputNumber += new ScanNumbersForm.NewNumberInputHandler(TransferData.RelocationNewNumberInput);
            dlg.OnTransferCommand += new ScanNumbersForm.TransferCommandHandler(TransferData.RelocationTransferCommand);
            dlg.OperationType = DeviceFolders.Operation.Relocation;
            dlg.ShowDialog();
            dlg.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

Обработчик события нажатия кнопки на вызванной форме: TextBoxForm.cs

```
 private void SkipButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            String ZONE_NAME = "";
            String STACK_NAME = "";
            int POCKET_NUMBER = 0;

            //создание и инициализация формы пакета труб
            ScanNumbersForm dlg = new ScanNumbersForm();

                //ввод складского объекта
                DataTable tbl = Nsi.GetSkladObjects();
                ZONE_NAME = ListBoxForm.InputValue("Выберите складской объект", tbl);
                //ввод номера штабеля
                tbl = Nsi.GetStacksBySkladObject(ZONE_NAME);
                STACK_NAME = ListBoxForm.InputValue("Выберите номер штабеля", tbl);

                //ввод номера кармана
                POCKET_NUMBER = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxForm.InputValue("Введите номер кармана"));

                dlg.Packet.Attributes["ZONE_NAME"] = ZONE_NAME;
                dlg.Packet.Attributes["STACK_NAME"] = STACK_NAME;
                dlg.Packet.Attributes["POCKET_NUMBER"] = POCKET_NUMBER;
                if (lbHead.Text == "Сканирование штрихкода штабеля ")
                {
                    dlg.OnInputNumber += new ScanNumbersForm.NewNumberInputHandler(TransferData.PrihodNewNumberInput);
                    dlg.OnTransferCommand += new ScanNumbersForm.TransferCommandHandler(TransferData.PrihodTransferCommand);
                    dlg.OperationType = DeviceFolders.Operation.Prihod;
                }
                else
                {
                    dlg.OnInputNumber += new ScanNumbersForm.NewNumberInputHandler(TransferData.RelocationNewNumberInput);
                    dlg.OnTransferCommand += new ScanNumbersForm.TransferCommandHandler(TransferData.RelocationTransferCommand);
                    dlg.OperationType = DeviceFolders.Operation.Relocation;
                }
                dlg.ShowDialog();
                dlg.Dispose();

    }
```

Пробовал добавлять в обработчик `SkipButton_Click` такую штуку:

`DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;` и `Close();`

Но это не помогло и не сработало

Comment: Вам надо закрывать форму до вот этого `dlg.ShowDialog();`

Comment: @tym32167 т.е. нужно закрыть в `MainForm.cs?` с помощью `dlg.Close();`??

Comment: Вы можете закрыть `MainForm` только с помощью методов `MainForm`, то есть не `dlg.Close();`, а просто `Close();`

Comment: Идея в том, чтобы управлением открытием-закрытием проводить в основной форме (при выходе из первой формы проверять DialogResult, и открывать вторую, если был Cancel). Во второй форме не надо ничего делать (она не знает, что за ней может быть открыто другое окно, т.к. к этому моменту она уже закрыта).

Comment: вы не можете из дочернего модального окна закрыть родительское. поэтому и не получается. то, что вы в ShowDialog не передаете родителя, у вас все равно будет модальное окно. чтобы окно было немодальным надо делать Show.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать пользовательский Диалог с пользовательскими элементами, а по результату выполните в родительской форме самозакрытие и открытие другой формы. Например так: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569489/easiest-way-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-which-returns-a-value

Comment: @tym32167 я пробовал через `Close();` , но это не работает по какой-то причине

Comment: Вы что то сделали и у вас что то не работает по какой то причине. Мне не ясно ни что именно вы сделали, ни какой результат ожидаете, ни какая проблема у вас возникает. С той информацией, что вы представили, мне вам нечего подсказать.